# Which kind of model should I be looking at if I'm trying to estimate volume for 3D objects?

Tags: models, model-request

I'm trying to navigate the world of LLMs and understand which classes of models are ideal for which use case. So I'm wondering, for problems related to 3D volume estimation, which class of models are most likely to be able to solve it?

Some sort of multimodal thing, like Flamingo? Or one of the vision / OCR specific classes of models?